# Compare values of two dictionaries in Python 3.7

Tags: python

I have two dataframes df_orig and df_mod with following values.

```
df_orig 

id     values
a      123 | 345`$ | 657
b      345 | 123 | 345
c      564 | 356

df_mod  

id     values
a      256 | 345 | 657
b      345 | 123/+ | 345
```

How can I compare the values of two dataframes per column and found out the difference. I have converted the dataframes to dictionaries but I did not find an efficient way to compare the values per key.

```
syn_dict_orig = dict(zip(df_orig.id, df_orig.values))
syn_dict_mod = dict(zip(df_orig.id, df_mod.values))

for key,value in syn_dict_orig.items():
    if (key not in syn_dict_mod.keys()):
        print ('id lost', '-->' ,key)
```

The expected output is:

```
diff
id     diff
a      256 | 345`$ | 345    
b      123 | 123/+
c      564 | 356
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe diff them without converting?

Comment: You're not comparing values, you're only comparing keys.

Comment: Why are you using dicts? I'm sure there's a way to do this with Pandas, though I don't know off the top of my head. (You are using Pandas, right?) You'd just need to do something like `.explode('values')` first to be able to compare them. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) (although at least you've given the context here).

Comment: Why are you printing `id lost -->` if that's not part of your desired output? That code doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you convert each value into a set of its components, you can use set operations to compare them.

Comment: Shouldn't `123` be in the output for `a`?

Comment: Are the lengths of the `values` always equal for matching `id`s?